# どれ as an attribute

Tags: grammar, words, interjections, interrogatives, attributive

I found this sentence and I wonder whether I understand it correctly:

> **どれ**腹の傷をおみせ、薬草をぬってあげよう。

The どれ there looks to me like “whichever” or “all”, so I’d get the sentence as “Let me look at all the wounds on your belly…” However I could not find a fitting example in a dictionary, so I am not sure.

If there’d be も, I’d have no doubts, as it then simply means “any”. But this sentence has no も and is not negative.

So, do I get it right? Does this use of question word as an attribute of a noun mean “any, all”?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 「**どれ**腹{はら}の傷{きず}をおみせ、薬草{やくそう}をぬってあげよう。」

You are "seeing" the wrong 「どれ」 here, which is the 「どれ」("which one") from こそあど.

This 「どれ」 is an ***interjection*** meaning "***now***", "***well***", "***let's see***", etc.  It is most often used when checking on or taking a (close) look at something.  We also say 「どら」、「どれどれ」, etc. for the same purpose.

***"Now, let me see the wound on your tummy.  I'll put some herbal medicine on it for you***."

The author could have (or rather should have) inserted a comma right after the 「どれ」 for clarity's sake.